# Can we make substitutions based on rules from a file?

Tags: substitute, replace

I've been using the command mode for making replacements in a file. Something like `:%s/foo/bar/g` and to make a series of replacements:

```
:%s/i/1/g | :%s/j/2/g | :%s/k/3/g | :%s/l/4/g | ...
```

This line exists in the command history but I was curious if these commands can be pulled from a file with contents like:

```
%s/i/1/g
%s/j/2/g
%s/k/3/g
%s/l/4/g
.
.
.
```

If this is a possibility, it will be easy to have several replacement combinations in different files. Thanks for your thoughts and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can store the list of Ex commands to a file and then use the [`:source`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Asource) command to execute the commands in the file.

By convention, you would save the commands to a file using the `*.vim` extension. That will also get Vim to help you with proper syntax highlighting, automatic indentation, etc. for the `vim` filetype.

If you store the file under the `~/.vim` directory (or some other location listed in [`'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27)), then you can also use the [`:runtime`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Aruntime) command to execute it. (It's essentially the same as `:source`, but you don't need to specify the full path to your runtime directory.)

If you currently have the list of commands you want to save into a script in the command history, you might want to use the [`q:`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#q%3A) normal mode command to open a window with the command-line history, so you can copy the commands from there and paste them into a buffer where you can edit, rearrange them and save them into a `*.vim` file.